# Create PostGIS trigger that splits lines

Tags: postgis, postgresql, trigger

I have a table with LINESTRING where one condition is for lines to be composed of only 2 vertices. I want the user to be able to create, or import lines with more than 2 vertices, but upon feature creation, the line would be split into 2-vertices lines.

I have created a trigger function for this purpose, using an [example](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/breaking-linestring-into-segments.html) from [Paul Ramsey's blog](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca).

This is the trigger function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_vertex()
RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
IF (ST_NPoints(NEW.he_geom))= 2 THEN 
RETURN NEW;
END IF;

IF (ST_NPoints(NEW.he_geom))>2 THEN

INSERT INTO he_temp VALUES (NEW.*);

INSERT INTO he_temp (he_id, orientation, inclination, he_geom)
WITH segments AS (
    SELECT he_id, orientation, inclination, ST_SetSRID(ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(lag((pt).geom, 1, NULL) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY he_id ORDER BY he_id, (pt).path), (pt).geom)), 22780) AS geom
      FROM (SELECT he_id, orientation, inclination, ST_DumpPoints(he_geom) AS pt FROM he_temp) as dumps)
SELECT he_id, orientation, inclination, geom FROM segments WHERE geom IS NOT NULL;

DELETE FROM he_temp WHERE ST_NPoints(he_geom) > 2;

INSERT INTO horizontal_element (orientation, inclination, he_geom)
SELECT orientation, inclination, he_geom FROM he_temp;

TRUNCATE TABLE he_temp;

END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The only way I found to implement this trigger is to insert lines with more than 2 vertices into a temporary table (he_temp), execute the split there and copy the split elements back to the primary table (he). After each insert, the temp table would be cleared.

I ran a few tests and it seems to work.

So my question is, is there a way to implement the same logic without using a temporary table, cause I have a feeling my implementation might have some issues, although I fail to see them at the moment?